# Calendar displaying too many subscription connections

Tags: macos, calendar

I have an older iMac running High Sierra 10.13.6. Recently the Apple Calendar app is displaying unusable subscription connections. The Calendar sidebar is shown in the image below.

[image]

In the image above, these subscription connections all contain a warning. This warning message is shown below.

[image]

I have over a hundred of these. My question: is there any way to unsubscribe from all these instead of doing it one at a time, and does anyone have a clue as to what caused all these?